# Having issues finding the bug with implementing Conway's Game of Life. Below is the source code

Tags: c

The rules of Conway's Game of life is each cell on a grid has two states: living or dead. 1. If a living cell has fewer than 2 or more than 3 neighbors, the cell dies. 2.If a living cell has 2 or 3 neighbors, it lives on. 3.If a dead cell has exactly 3 neighbors, it is born in the next generation.

I first created two small 5 by 5 grid with arrays to contain the cells. One array is for the previous configuration and another array is for the updated new array. "-" symbolizes a dead cell and "O" symbolizes an alive cell. I set up a loop that prints out the initial/old configuration, update the configuration and store it in the new array, and rewrote the old array with the updated array. Then the terminal would be emptied out. The next iteration would then print the updated world. However, the second generation is incorrect. I'm not sure where the problem lies.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void update_world(void);
void print_world(void);
int check(int width, int height);

//create a 5 by 5 array which would be the "world"
char cell[5][5]; 
char new_cell[5][5];

int main(void) {
  
  //initialize array to "-"s (dead)
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
      cell[i][j] = '-';
    }
  }
  
  //initialize configuration ie. put some life into the world 
  cell[0][1] = 'O';
  cell[4][0] = 'O';
  cell[1][2] = 'O';
  cell[1][4] = 'O';
  cell[4][4] = 'O';
  cell[0][2] = 'O';

  //outer loop for iteration of each cycle
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) //goes for 10 generations
  {
    print_world(); 
    update_world();
    //write new cell into old cell before the new cell updates
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
      {
        cell[i][j] = new_cell[i][j];
      }
    }
    sleep(1);
    printf("\033[2J\033[H"); //clear terminal 
  }
}

//print out the world onto terminal
void print_world(void)
{
  for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++)
  {
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    {
      if (row % 5 == 0)
        printf("\n");
      printf("%c", cell[row][column]);
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
}

//update world
void update_world(void)
{
  //traverse world
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
      //checks the conditions to decide whether the cell is alive or dead in the next generation
      if (check(i, j) == 1) 
        new_cell[i][j] = '-'; //cell dies
      else if (check(i,j) == 0){
        new_cell[i][j] = 'O'; //cell is born
      }
      else 
        new_cell[i][j] = cell[i][j]; //cell stays the same
    }
  } 
}

//check if cell should die, be born, or stay as is
int check(int width, int height)
{
  int alive = 0;

  //traverse cell's neightboring cells (including itself)
  for (int h = height - 1; h <= height + 1; h++)
  {
    for (int w = width - 1; w <= width + 1; w++)
    {
      //if cell (h,w) is a surrounding cell, within bounds of the grid, and is alive 
      if (!(h == height && w == width) && h >= 0 && h < 5
       && w >= 0 && w < 5 && cell[h][w] == 79)
        alive++;//increment alive count
    }
  } 

  //check conditions 
  if (alive > 3 || alive < 2)
    return 1; //cell dies
  else if (alive == 3)
    return 0; //cell is born or lives on to next generation
  return 2; //alive count = 2, nothing changes
}
```

Comment: You have `cell[h][w] == 79)` at one point — what's that 79?  Is it `'O'`?   Why didn't you write that?  Or use named constants: `enum { DEAD = '-', LIVE = 'O' };`?

Comment: Tip: Avoid global variables at all costs. They're nothing but trouble. Pass your world(s) through as argument(s).

Comment: Tip If you're coping one contiguous array to another, just use `memcpy()` instead of this much more time consuming nested loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You switch coordinates in `check()`.

In `update_world()` you call it with `i` and `j` for `cell[i][j]`, and these parameters are named `width` (for `i`) and `height` (for `j`) inside `check()`.

But then you test `cell[h][w]`, with `h` running from `height - 1` to `height + 1` and `w` running from `width - 1` to `width + 1`. It should be `cell[w][h]` instead.

***Other note:***

Since the return value of `check()` will not change between calls, you can simplify the body of the loops in `update_world()` by caching the value. Anyway, it can be simpler with a `switch`:

```c
          //checks the conditions to decide whether the cell is alive or dead in the next generation
          switch (check(i, j))
          {
          case 1:
            new_cell[i][j] = '-'; //cell dies
            break;
          case 0:
            new_cell[i][j] = 'O'; //cell is born
            break;
          default:
            new_cell[i][j] = cell[i][j]; //cell stays the same
            break;
          }
```